# Is having union in σ the same as having two queries?

Tags: relational-algebra

I have this question:

> What are the names of Employees in Boston or Chicago?

With these relations:

`employees(id, name)` and `workIn(id, city)`

Where the `id` in both relations refer to the same thing (the id of the employee)

The query I wrote was:

`Π name (σ city="Boston" U city="Chicago"(employees ⋈ workIn))`

The solution given to the question was:

```
Π name (σ city="Boston"(employees ⋈ workIn)) U
Π name (σ city="Chicago"(employees ⋈ workIn))
```

Would the two queries return the same result? Or is my query just wrong?

If my query is wrong, what would the difference be in values returned?

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras).They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. In particular, we don't know what expressions you are allowed to write after `σ`. (Although what you wrote won't be allowed.)

Comment: A standard comment of mine >> Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you will find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong & right. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. << Eg: You will find no justification for `U` after `σ`. But per my earlier comment you might or might not be allowed to write more than one `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong since you are using the Union operator (`U`) between two logical conditions `city="Boston" U city="Chicago"` (which does not make sense, since the Union is a set operator, not a logical operator).

The logical operator to use in a condition is the “or” (written `∨`), which makes a compound condition true when either of the two components are true (or both are true, but this is not possible here).

So a correct expression is:

```
Π name (σ city="Boston" ∨ city="Chicago"(employees ⋈ workIn))
```

and this is equivalent to the expression with the Union:

```
Π name (σ city="Boston"(employees ⋈ workIn)) U
Π name (σ city="Chicago"(employees ⋈ workIn))
```